# What does "(_, i) => expression" mean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, parameters, arrow-functions

I saw the explanation of [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) on MDN, and at the bottom there is a code block like this below:

```
const range = (start, stop, step) => Array.from({ length: (stop - start) / step + 1}, (_, i) => start + (i * step));
```

I did not understand why parameter can be like `(_, i)`, can somebody explain that to me?

Comment: This is an indication that the first arg (which is the element at index `i`) in that code it's irrelevant, useless, Etc., because the author wants to use the index `i` only.

Comment: Technically it stores the value in argument `_` and the index in argument `i`. But the value is never used. It's convention to call such unused arguments `_`. But you could also use any other name, it's just a variable name.

Answer (score 3):

In the JavaScript developer ecosystem, it's a *coding-convention* to use a singular underscore `_` character to denote a "discarded" or "irrelevant" parameter or value that must still be specified.

It is *not* a part of the JavaScript language, however. (So you can still use `_` as a variable identifier).

Some languages, like C# 7, *do* give `_` special-treatment - however.